# Rails remove id=nil from the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Query is -

```
result = Table.select('count(*) as totalCount, sum(price) as totalSum').where('user = ?', id)
```

Returns

```
{
  "id": null,
  "totalCount": 3,
  "totalSum": 300,
}
```

But I don't want id. How to remove that `id:null`

Comment: You need the primary key as you as querying on it. U can use pluck but it will give u an array not obj

Answer (score 1):

use pluck instead of select.

I have not tried this but thinking this should work.

```
Table.where('user = ?', id).pluck('count(*), sum(price)')
```

Comment: the only caveat here is that by doing .pluck you're forcing evaluation of the ActiveRecord::Relation. That's fine in most cases but it means you cannot chain any further Relations onto that unless that is defined in a scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass for a result :

```
result = result.as_json(:except => [:id])
```

ID will be except for result.